# Per-host New Relic Keys with Capistrano2-MultiStage Deploy

Tags: capistrano, chef-infra, newrelic

I'm using Capistrano 2 with the multistage extension to deploy a rails app. I have many servers and only one New Relic Pro account. I'm using Roundsman to deploy chef recipes via capistrano. Link to relevant chef script  https://github.com/escapestudios-cookbooks/newrelic/blob/master/recipes/server_monitor_agent.rb

I have two stages, staging and production. These are relevant sections of config/deploy/staging.rb file

```
 set :sidekiq_host, "sqstaging.com"
 set :webapp_host,  "staging.com"
 set :db_host, "dbstaging.com"
 set :stage, "production-#{application}"
 set :rails_env, "staging"
 set :sidekiq_env, "sidekiq_staging"
 set :user,      "jpubu33"
 set :port, 333
 set :deploy_to, "/mnt/www/#{application}"
 set :branch, "master"

server webapp_host, :app, {
    :newrelic, {:server_monitoring => {:license => "cfdfdsvv45b" } }
    }

server sidekiq_host, :app, {
    :newrelic, {:server_monitoring => {:license => "fveveveuvevhuevuiehv" } }
    }

server db_host, :app,  {
    :newrelic, {:server_monitoring => {:license => "vevhuevuihuvhrubrhub" } }
    }
```

Sadly the new relic key ends up being the cookbook's default of CHANGE_ME.

However if I were simply to add this to the file, it sets all server to the same new relic key

```
set :newrelic, { :server_monitoring => {:license => "vehfhdufuehfheuhr948hvdfdsgb" } }
```

I'm wondering why the per-server config isn't working, and if there is a way to use the per-server variable later- for instance can I do something like

```
 set :myKey, webapp_host => {:newrelic}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have just one primary New Relic account. Since license keys are per-account, if that is the case, you can use the same license key for each of your reporting servers, and each host will appear under its own host name. If this configuration doesn't meet your needs, you can get further help at http://support.newrelic.com/.

Comment: We have two New Relic accounts- one is pro, one is free. We can only afford one server in our pro account. The rest must be licensed under the free account, which is a different key. Our New Relic Rep said there was no way to combine pro and free in the same account/with the same key sadly.